# How can I add custom fields in cms edit page (Admin Panel)?

Tags: magento, content-management-system, admin

I am facing an issue in Magento. I want to add some custom fields to Magento Admin Panel CMS Edit Page. I got a page while searching where it describes adding a custom field in CMS page:  http://blog.flexishore.com/2011/08/add-custom-field-to-cms-page/ .

I have followed every step in this, but I am still getting an error `Call to undefined function getLoad()`.

Can anyone here explain me how to add custom fields in CMS page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this article (http://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-custom-attribute-to-a-cms-page/) as well, it's more simple, maybe it will be helpful for you.

Also don't forget about cache, I recommend you disable it when you are testing your own modules.

Comment: Cache should not (always) be disabled when testing an own module, because you would not spot cache-related problems.